# After using subl command, prompt in Terminal disappears

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext3

For some reason, after Sublime Text 3 upgraded itself, my subl command hasn't been working properly. When I type in subl xxx, xxx folder will not be opened as a project, and there is no next terminal prompt. Instead, I'd have to ctrl-c to get my prompt back. Using subl . also doesn't open the current working directory as a project in Sublime. And again, the terminal doesn't prompt me until I hit ctrl-c. Anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue and what I did was to set up my shortcut again.

- remove the `subl` file from the `/usr/local/bin` folder, you can do this from the command line by running this command `rm /usr/local/bin/subl`
- copy the new sublime binary file to the bin folder, you can do so by running this command from your terminal `cp /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin`
- restart your terminal and sublime should be working perfectly well now

If not, just re-install sublime to your machine and follow the steps above to copy the subl executable file to the bin folder